# How to install libxml2-dev (32-bit) package on a 64-bit Ubuntu (11.10)

Tags: installation, package-management, development, 32-bit

I want to run an binary for a 32-bit application which is dynaically linked to the libxml2 on a 64-bit Ubuntu (11.10). I have found and installed 32-bit libraries for most of the other libraries used, however I cannot find a package to install all 32-bit version of libxml2-dev. 
What packages do I have to install in order to make it run?

starting the application will lead to the following error  libxml2.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

I succeeded to install a 32 bit version of zlib in /ust/lib32 but I cannot find a 32 bit version of libxml2.

The synaptic package manager list a libxml2-dev:i386 package. However since this eants to uninstall almost all installed packages I assume that this is for a pure 64 bit Linix

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I came across another way of having lib32 version of libxml2.so installed on 64-bit Ubuntu (12.04) - installing Adobe Reader. It's one of popular applications that most of people would need, so it will make you feel a bit more comfortable than obtaining libxml2 by doing something else.

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

(Cribbed from http://www.techheadz.co.uk/222.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

But incidentally, 32-bit versions were available to me with the installations of Collabnet Subversion (solved my libxml2 for 32 bit Linux). And then all other 32 bit libraries were sourced from Intel's 32 bit compiler installation.

I had to put both these directories into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get around screwing up other things on my system.